# How to find a folder in which a folder exists

Tags: python, json, directory

> I have a python file called main.py
> which is in my project/src folder

```
import json
import os

with open("../dependencies/data/foobar.json", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    for results in data:
    result = data.get("foobar")
    print(re)
```

I also have a json file in project/dependencies/data/foobar.json

I want to acces it using os module.

I want it to find the folder even if when calling the file in terminal from a different directory.

> The problem is when I call the file from the src folder in terminal. It is working fine.

> But when I am in the project folder in the terminal, It is throwing an error.

**Is there any way to solve this problem using python**

**Thanks for helping out**

Comment: When you use a relative path, it's relative SO it depends on where you run it. To run code independently from where you run it, use absolute path

Comment: Can you explain how to do that